# Why does this works with vectors but not with strings?

Tags: c++, string, windows, vector

**Why in this code this works**

```
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"
#include "string.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<string> myvect;
    string temp;
    string temp2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cin >> temp;
        myvect.push_back(temp);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        temp2 = myvect[i];
        cout << temp2 << endl;
    }
}
```

while doing temp2 = myvect[i] it puts in the whole string.
but while i do temp2 = temp[i] it only puts in the one character of the string.

Shouldn't both should give the same result. Isn't the string pointing to the first element of the string.

Comment: `doesn't work` is not description of the problem. It only states there is a problem. Please provide [mcve] when it doesn't work. You can use this as starting point: https://godbolt.org/z/5h7bKTrMo

Comment: temp is an std::string that holds chars. So what behaviour do you expect when accessing the chars of a string?

Comment: *Isn't the string pointing to the first element of the string.* You're confusing `std::string` with `const char*`. But even then, indexing a vector of strings is different than indexing a single string.

Comment: A `string` is a sequence of `char`, a `vector<string>` is a sequence of `string`. So `temp[i]` references a `char` and `myvect[i]` references a `string`. Not sure why you would expect anything else.

Comment: `#include "string.h"` -- This is not the correct header.  It is `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different containers. One beeing the `std::string` which stores and `char*` or an array of characters, and the other beeing the `std::vector` which, in your case, stores an array of `std::string`s.

```
char chArr[5];
int iArr[5];
std::string string;     // basically a char* with extra data and functions
std::vector<std::string> vector;

chArr[0];   // returns first char in array
iArr[0];    // returns first int in array
string[0];  // returns first char in string
vector[0];  // retunrs first element in vector, in this case a string
```

Answer (score 0):

> doing temp2 = myvect[i] it puts in the whole string

`temp2` is a string, but `myvect` is a vector with elements of string. when you index `myvect` with square brackets, what you get is the elements of `myvect`, i.e. string.

> do temp2 = temp[i] it only puts in the one character of the string

`temp` is a string, so when you index it with square brackets, you get its element type, i.e. character (string is a special kind of vector in C++, its elements are characters).

In summary, you may be confusing the concepts of `string` and `vector<string>`. They are both vectors, of course, but the elements of one are strings and the elements of the other are characters.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused  in difference between how vectors work and how strings work.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```cpp
cin >> temp;
```

It will fill `temp` with the user input (more on that [here](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/#cin_and_strings)), meaning that `temp`'s content will be replaced with a new string (3 times in your case).

Then, if you do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    temp2 = temp[i];
    cout << temp2 << endl;
}
```

This will read the first three characters of the last input (which is also unsafe, as the input string could be smaller).

For example, to concatenate the first 3 user inputs:

```
    string temp2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        string temp;
        cin >> temp;
        temp2 += temp;
    }
    cout << temp2 << endl;
```

I am not sure to understand what's your intent though, if you want to only consider single characters, you might want to use `char` instead of `string`.